# Multi-tab pdf reader and a way of opening pdfs in the same tab but not from within the app?

Tags: pdf, okular

I'm using qpdfview and okular. They support tabs. But I do not see how to do the following:

a) open (double click) files and have them open in one window as tabs
b) "merge" all open windows into one with tabs.

Am looking for a reader that can open everything in one window or a way of making this happen via some config.

Comment: For now, I might just use firefox. Seems better than chrome and has the roughly desired behaviour. Might be a bit heavy.

Comment: You can achieve this via Okular.You have to go to the Settings->Configure Okular->General->Program Features->Open new files in tabs. I don't think it's the default option but rather you have to enable it.

Comment: And if you're concerned with the memory usage , go to **Settings->Configure Okular->Performance->Memory Usage** and set it to **low**. You can also set it to **Greedy** which makes your PDF viewing faster but uses much more memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is a way:

for qpdfview:

- copy `/usr/share/applications/qpdfview.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/qpdfview.desktop`
- edit `~/.local/share/applications/qpdfview.desktop` so that the Exec line reads `Exec=qpdfview --unique %f`

for okular there might be a similar way yet i did not find one

Answer (score 6):

For Okular you have to check this : **Settings->Configure Okular->General->Program Features->Open new files in tabs**.

Answer (score 2):

**Mendeley**, primarily a reference manager, has a built-in pdf reader. PDF files open up in Tabs from within or outside the application. Just try it and it may well become your default PDF reader app due to speed and convenience.